Allow excluding/including/only having Staging Ground posts in a Custom filter
Currently, posts that are in the Staging Ground and not graduated yet are shown on the site in all regular lists of questions. This includes custom filters.
However, I have custom filters where I wish to only check questions. I do not want to do a mode switch between SG items and regular questions.
There should be an options to exclude or include Staging Ground posts in a custom filter. It might even be useful to have a custom filter with only Staging Ground posts.

"It might even be useful to have a custom filter with only Staging Ground posts." Yes. I absolutely would use this. Right now, the fact that SG is live is not really discoverable.

Staging ground is described as a 'private space' so why is it ever-present? Is it because it is a new "feature" that admin want everybody to see? I would like to filter it, or reposition it into the review queues – which is where it belongs.

@WeatherVane because it isn't a private space. That's a mis-leading label, given anyone with 500 rep can access it.

Thank you! It makes absolutely no sense to have a staging ground if the results still show up in a regular feed. If anything, it's a giant "this question may be low quality!" flag that draws the eyes, which in UX terms is the opposite of the goal. A user not specifically looking for SG questions wants to hide SG, not make it stand out more.

Stupid, but more inline with the goal solution: Remove the SG banner from questions and add a "Graduated from SG" banner to questions that aren't in SG.  But that's ridiculous. Just add a checkbox so that I can toggle SG questions on and off in my feed

@Mars I disagree. what I see as the main benefit of SG is that there's a dedicated stage for quality improvement before opening up for answering. though I agree that it would be a plus to be able to hide SG stuff in regular question listings.

@Mars go to your profile -> settings -> "Show Staging Ground questions" https://i.sstatic.net/pBa3Bc0f.png

@starball I didn't realize that SG questions couldn't be answered! I definitely appreciate that. Still don't want SG questions in my questions feed though
