How can I opt out of seeing staging ground questions in custom filters?
How can I opt out staging ground questions being watched?
At my specifically watched tags (c++) I don't want to see questions that didn't make it through that stage.
The general concept seems to work better regarding quality than the "triage queue" so far though.

Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/430482/6296561

@Zoe yup, definitely related, if not a dupe.
